# Не работает геолокация в react-native

Tags: javascript, android, frontend, react-native, геолокация

Я создаю проект при помощи expo:

```
expo init geotest
```

Добавляю разрешение в app.json:

```
"android": {
    "permissions": [
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    ]
}
```

Устанавливаю библиотеку:

```
npm install react-native-geolocation-service
```

В App.js вставляю вот этот код из примера:

https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service/blob/master/example/App.js

Но при вызове Geolocation.getCurrentPosition получаю предупреждение:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNFusedLocation.getCurrentPosition')]
```

Уже все перепробовал, ничего не пойму, помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Подсказали решение. Можно использовать expo-location. Она работает без проблем docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location